# ¿Cómo puedo hacer una subconsulta en sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, tablas, subconsultas

Tengo esta consulta sql server

```
SELECT NUM_DOC, FHA_ALTA, USUARIO, ULTIMOUSR, ACTUALIZADO, NOMBREDA,
       STATUSDA, CIUDADDA, PLANVIDA, OBSERVDA, OBSERVDA2, DIRDA,
       TELDA, PAISDA, NOMCIADA, FORMPADA, NOMCAR1DA, NOMCAR2DA,
       NOMCAR3DA, NOMCAR4DA, NOMCAR5DA, PASEDA, CUPAGDA, NOMFOL1DA,
       NOMFOL2DA, NOMFOL3DA, FOLEX1DA, FOLEX2DA, FOLEX3DA, FOLEX4DA,
       FOLEX5DA, FOLEX6DA, AUDITDA, HORASALIDA, HORAENTRAD, PROGEODA,
       CVEGRLDA, GARANTIADA, CVEESTDA1, CVEESTDA2, CVEESTDA3,
       CVEESTDA4, CVEESTDA5, CVEESTDA6, CVEESTDA7, CVEESTDA8,
       CVEESTDA9, CVEESTDA10, CVEESTDA11, CVEESTDA12, CVEESTDA13,
       CVEESTDA14, CVEESTDA15, CVEESTDA16, INIREGDA, HORAMOVDA,
       CREDITODA, CUENTASDA, RFCDA, DIRCIADA, CIUDCIADA, FACTADA,
       HORLIMDA, TIPTARDA, CVEGPODA, CAJASEDA, ORIGENDA, MASCREDA,
       TARNINDA, ESTADODA, FOLCEDDA, NOMBR_DA, APPAT_DA, APMAT_DA,
       EMAIL_DA, CODPOSDA, TELEFODA, TIPCOMDA, INIRESDA, HORARESDA,
       OBSERVDA4, OBSERVDA5, MOTCAMODA, MOTCAMBDA, MOTCAMUDA,
       MOTCAMTDA, MOTTARBDA, MOTTARUDA, MOTTARTDA, NOMFACT, FHAHISTDA,
       TITHUEDA, ANTHABDA, COLCIADA, EDOCIADA, PAISCIADA, CPCIADA,
       NOMAGEDA, DIRAGEDA, COLAGEDA, CIUDAGEDA, EDOAGEDA, PAISAGEDA,
       CPAGEDA, COLONIDA, USOHOTELDA, DELHUEDA, DELAGEDA, DELCIADA,
       RFCHUEDA, RFCAGEDA, FE_CPAGO, FE_C2PAGO, FE_FPAGO, FE_CTAPAG,
       TARJ_NUM, TARJ_FHA, TARJ_COD, NORESMDA, NUMT_DE, TIPOCUPON,
       MOTIVOFORZ, RATELISTDA, HISTORYDA, MOTIVGENDA, USERBILLING,
       PCBILLING, NUMEXTERIOR, NUMINTERIOR, NUMEXTERIORCIA,
       NUMINTERIORCIA, NUMEXTERIORAGE, NUMINTERIORAGE, FHAENTDA,
       FHASALDA, FHAEXTDA, FHADEPDA, FECHRESDA, FHARESDA, FORRESDA,
       FHALIMDA, FHAREGDA, MOTCAMDDA, MOTTARDDA, FHAMOVDA, VIPDA,
       NOTARDA, UPSELLDA, ISBILLING, APLIRENTDA, NUMRESDA, NUMHABDA,
       DEPOSIDA, NUMPERDA, TARIFADA, NUMCUADA, CARGO1DA, CUENCAR1DA,
       CARGO2DA, CUENCAR2DA, CARGO3DA, CUENCAR3DA, CARGO4DA, CUENCAR4DA,
       CARGO5DA, CUENCAR5DA, FACTURADA, NUMHUESDA, TPOCAM1DA, TPOCAM2DA,
       TPOCAM3DA, TPOCAM4DA, TPOCAM5DA, TPOCAM6DA, CTAMSRDA, HABEX1DA,
       HABEX2DA, HABEX3DA, HABEX4DA, HABEX5DA, NUMNINDA, NUMREGDA,
       ESTRESDA, NUMVIPDA, NUMEXTDA, NUMCANDA, CANREGDA, ESTCALDA,
       MONCREDA, NUMLISDA, EDAD01DA, EDAD02DA, EDAD03DA, EDAD04DA,
       EDAD05DA, EDAD06DA, EDAD07DA, EDAD08DA, EDAD09DA, PORCOMDA,
       TICAMODA, TARTARIFAR, MOTTARODA, HABGRUDA, CANCUP, IDHISTORIAL,
       NUMREGSTRDA, FHA_CAMBIO
FROM F_DB_DATOSENC
WHERE (NUM_DOC = @NUM_DOC)
```

y necesito que una campos que son los siguientes: Clave Grupo, Fha. Entrada, Fha. Salida, Nombre, Fha. Reservacion, Ejecutivo, Contacto, Tipo
Que viene de esta tabla F_DB_GPO50ENC, me comentaron que puede ser con una subconsulta pero no se como hacerlo. De antemano gracias.

Comment: Hola PabloXD, bienvenido, tu pregunta se parece a "tengo este ejercicio, háganlo", este tipo de preguntas, no suelen ser bien recibidas, te sugiero que la edites, y muestres que has intentado, para saber que formas parte de la resolución de tu problema, mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, obtengas una mejor respuesta, evitar votos negativos y/o que sea eliminada.

aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener una medalla!.

Comment: Como se relacionan las filas de ambas tablas? Generalmente no se una una subconsulta sino un `JOIN`. Existe mucha documentación acerca de como usar `JOIN` y es algo básico que debes de aprender, por lo que sugiero que leas al respecto y regreses con dudas específicas y ejemplos de lo que has intentado.

Comment: Otro punto importante es que esa tabla necesita estar normalizada. Sería importante que el equipo busque a alguien que sepa de diseño de bases de datos antes de que el sistema se vuelva una pesadilla imposible de mantener.

Answer (score -1):

Puedes probar después de tu primer select hacer algo como

```
(SELECT Clave_Grupo FROM F_DB_GPO50ENC WHERE NUM_DOC = @NUM_DOC) AS Clave_Grupo,
```

Answer (score -1):

```sql
SELECT NUM_DOC, FHA_ALTA, USUARIO, ULTIMOUSR, ACTUALIZADO, NOMBREDA,
       STATUSDA, CIUDADDA, PLANVIDA, OBSERVDA, OBSERVDA2, DIRDA,
       TELDA, PAISDA, NOMCIADA, FORMPADA, NOMCAR1DA, NOMCAR2DA,
       NOMCAR3DA, NOMCAR4DA, NOMCAR5DA, PASEDA, CUPAGDA, NOMFOL1DA,
       NOMFOL2DA, NOMFOL3DA, FOLEX1DA, FOLEX2DA, FOLEX3DA, FOLEX4DA,
       FOLEX5DA, FOLEX6DA, AUDITDA, HORASALIDA, HORAENTRAD, PROGEODA,
       CVEGRLDA, GARANTIADA, CVEESTDA1, CVEESTDA2, CVEESTDA3,
       CVEESTDA4, CVEESTDA5, CVEESTDA6, CVEESTDA7, CVEESTDA8,
       CVEESTDA9, CVEESTDA10, CVEESTDA11, CVEESTDA12, CVEESTDA13,
       CVEESTDA14, CVEESTDA15, CVEESTDA16, INIREGDA, HORAMOVDA,
       CREDITODA, CUENTASDA, RFCDA, DIRCIADA, CIUDCIADA, FACTADA,
       HORLIMDA, TIPTARDA, CVEGPODA, CAJASEDA, ORIGENDA, MASCREDA,
       TARNINDA, ESTADODA, FOLCEDDA, NOMBR_DA, APPAT_DA, APMAT_DA,
       EMAIL_DA, CODPOSDA, TELEFODA, TIPCOMDA, INIRESDA, HORARESDA,
       OBSERVDA4, OBSERVDA5, MOTCAMODA, MOTCAMBDA, MOTCAMUDA,
       MOTCAMTDA, MOTTARBDA, MOTTARUDA, MOTTARTDA, NOMFACT, FHAHISTDA,
       TITHUEDA, ANTHABDA, COLCIADA, EDOCIADA, PAISCIADA, CPCIADA,
       NOMAGEDA, DIRAGEDA, COLAGEDA, CIUDAGEDA, EDOAGEDA, PAISAGEDA,
       CPAGEDA, COLONIDA, USOHOTELDA, DELHUEDA, DELAGEDA, DELCIADA,
       RFCHUEDA, RFCAGEDA, FE_CPAGO, FE_C2PAGO, FE_FPAGO, FE_CTAPAG,
       TARJ_NUM, TARJ_FHA, TARJ_COD, NORESMDA, NUMT_DE, TIPOCUPON,
       MOTIVOFORZ, RATELISTDA, HISTORYDA, MOTIVGENDA, USERBILLING,
       PCBILLING, NUMEXTERIOR, NUMINTERIOR, NUMEXTERIORCIA,
       NUMINTERIORCIA, NUMEXTERIORAGE, NUMINTERIORAGE, FHAENTDA,
       FHASALDA, FHAEXTDA, FHADEPDA, FECHRESDA, FHARESDA, FORRESDA,
       FHALIMDA, FHAREGDA, MOTCAMDDA, MOTTARDDA, FHAMOVDA, VIPDA,
       NOTARDA, UPSELLDA, ISBILLING, APLIRENTDA, NUMRESDA, NUMHABDA,
       DEPOSIDA, NUMPERDA, TARIFADA, NUMCUADA, CARGO1DA, CUENCAR1DA,
       CARGO2DA, CUENCAR2DA, CARGO3DA, CUENCAR3DA, CARGO4DA, CUENCAR4DA,
       CARGO5DA, CUENCAR5DA, FACTURADA, NUMHUESDA, TPOCAM1DA, TPOCAM2DA,
       TPOCAM3DA, TPOCAM4DA, TPOCAM5DA, TPOCAM6DA, CTAMSRDA, HABEX1DA,
       HABEX2DA, HABEX3DA, HABEX4DA, HABEX5DA, NUMNINDA, NUMREGDA,
       ESTRESDA, NUMVIPDA, NUMEXTDA, NUMCANDA, CANREGDA, ESTCALDA,
       MONCREDA, NUMLISDA, EDAD01DA, EDAD02DA, EDAD03DA, EDAD04DA,
       EDAD05DA, EDAD06DA, EDAD07DA, EDAD08DA, EDAD09DA, PORCOMDA,
       TICAMODA, TARTARIFAR, MOTTARODA, HABGRUDA, CANCUP, IDHISTORIAL,
       NUMREGSTRDA, FHA_CAMBIO,
(select Clave_Grupo from F_DB_GPO50ENC where NUM_DOC = @NUM_DOC) AS 'Clave_Grupo',
(select Fha_Entrada from F_DB_GPO50ENC where NUM_DOC = @NUM_DOC) AS 'Fha_Entrada'
FROM F_DB_DATOSENC
WHERE (NUM_DOC = @NUM_DOC)
```

Esta no es la manera mas eficiente de hacerlo, pero si te funciona dale
Ahora bien toma en cuenta que si no llega a encontrar resultados te pondrá los campos en null

Comment: ¿Y para selecionar todos los campos?

Comment: @PabloXD "select *" te seleciona todo los campos.

Comment: Muchas gracias me has ayudado mucho.

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).